# I heard that Starcraft 2 now has something called global play?

Tags: starcraft-2

So it is possible for me to buy the SEA (South-east Asia) version and play it in Europe? (I'm based in Europe, but can buy the SEA digital version on battle net). Will it work?

Comment: I don't think it matters where you are, but rather what your account setting for location is. edit: for example, I have both a european and a US WoW account, which I can both access from where I live in The Netherlands.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked it up in my battle.net account.
The region in battle.net games just tells the game what server to connect to. Usually you would want the one closest to you to reduce lag as much as possible, but it is possible to play on the US server when you are in Europe, you just need to buy the US version of the game.

I noticed when I pressed the buy button for SC2 that there are no regions to choose from, it is locked in on 'global'. My guess is that they decided to let people from all servers play together, even though they are on different servers. In which case 'global play' would mean 'play globally'.

In short: Yes, you can play the SEA version in Europe, because there is no SEA version anymore, it's all one version now.